# Clean way to variable check + continue in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a relatively large `main()` function where I need to check a variable several times at different places in the function and then decide if I should `continue` the loop accordingly, like so:

```
def main():
    while True:
        ...
        if foo.check():
            reset()
            continue
        ...
```

Where `foo` is working as a time keeper of sorts, therefore I need to check it at *certain intervals*. These 3 lines appear about 3 to 5 times within the function.

I hate how dirty this is, so is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Are you 100 % sure your logic requires this arrangement into a loop with several interdependent `continue`s? That smell a bit.

Comment: @dedObed Well, I need to do several tasks in each iteration, but if something takes to long, I'm going back to the beginning of the loop. However, if that time threshold is passed, I don't want to stop the current task; I want to finish it first. The only way I can think of is to check the time after each task has been completed. I should add that encapsulating each of these tasks into separate functions isn't possible without the use of a bunch of global variables, which is _way_ worse in my humble opinion.

Comment: Aha, so the tasks have dependencies... could you elaborate on how? Maybe it is a nice linear pipeline?

Comment: @dedObed It is very linear, thankfully.

Comment: then maybe my answer would do? Or is there some another catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified enough information. I have two questions:

1. Is the call `foo.check()` *idempotent* meaning it always returns the same value and has no side-effects?
2. Is there a path through the code where you can reach the n<sup>th</sup> call to `foo.check()` *in the same block governed by the continue statement* without first calling the n-1<sup>th</sup> occurrence?

If, for example, the answer to the answer is yes and the second question were no, then you could remove all but the first occurrence of the call to `foo.check()` because the return value is clearly `False` or else you would never reach the second occurence.

If the answer to the first question is yes and the second is yes, then if the call to `foo_check()` is expensive, I might consider up front setting:

```
check_result = foo.check()
```

and then replacing every call to `foo_check()` with `check_result`. But ultimately you still need to do all the checks. But in all cases you can create a function `check_and_reset`:

```
def check_and_reset():
    if foo_check():
        reset()
        return True
    return False
```

Then your code becomes:

```
if check_and_reset(): continue
```

Comment: `foo.check()` always returns a boolean. Also, `foo.check()` changes over time, independent of what's going on in the rest of the block, so replacing each `foo.check()` with a single variable in the beginning of the loop is not viable.

Comment: Then I would suggest you create a function `check_and_reset` as I described above. That is really the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

Suggestion 1:
Create another function and call wherever you want.

Suggestion 2:
Make it as a one-liner

```
if foo.check():reset();continue
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "Create another function and call wherever you want". How does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a complex way to control some timing while running a set of tasks, I'd suggest to introduce a loop over the tasks. You can even easily pass partial results around:

```
def task_a():
    ...

def task_c(some_input):
    ...

tasks = [lambda x: task_a(), task_c]
last_stage_output = None

while True:
    reset()
    for task in tasks:
        if not foo.check():
            break 
        last_stage_output = task(last_stage_output)
```

This way, you make it clear that it is just a series of tasks to be done, it's simple to add, remove of reshuffle them, and the timing logic is concentrated in a single point.